# If 2 dropdown showing same value on selected index change

Tags: asp.net

I have been asked question on this scenario.There are 2 dropdownlist populating same data from same table one at top and other at bottom.when Item in first dropdownlist get selected,same item is shown in second dropdownlist and second item get selected,same item is selected in first.That means it is continuous loop.How to handle this situation. Don't want to use query
`select name from table where id = ddl1.selecteditem.value` and execute it.
On selectedindex function of dropdownlist1,he wrote like this

```
ddl2.selectedItem.value = ddl.selectedItem.value
```

and second list

```
ddl.selectedItem.value = ddl2.selectedItem.value
```

Does it possible to select the value from these 2 statement?I done like this,but not working.

Comment: what is your question exactly, you don't want to go to an infinite loop?

Comment: I am not able to change second dropdownlist value on selectedindexchange function of first dropdownlist.If the above logic is correct and loop get created,how to handle that loop?

Comment: you should have a temp variable in the middle between the two dropdownlists or u will end in looping through an infinite loop

Comment: also you should use some kind of a flag to check if the process is done so that it only enters each selectedindexchanged once.

Comment: @JuiTest: You should show what you've tried otherwise it's not possible to see what you could have done wrong (not even what's actually the problem).

Comment: I used the breakpoint.That function get called,and assign that value to second dropdownlist but not get display,when first dropdownlist item get selected.

Comment: ddl2.selectedItem.Text = ddl.selectedItem.Text instead of value,i wrote like this,then  on change the item of one dropdownlist,item in second dropdown list get changed

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the same value in both dropdownlists you need to do this in your dropdownlist1_selectedindexchanged:

```
DropDownList2.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
```

The same in dropdownlist2_selectedindexchanged:

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList2.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
```

This should keep the same value in both dropdownlists whenever they have been modified.